# Fill NA value color groupby version with mode Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

There is a way to do this without using join to perform better?

I'm want to fill color NA values by mode version and I did this... But finding mode first, and then creating a new column with join, by the code bellow:

Obs: I'm using the spark version 3.2, so I cannot use mode function and i cannot update to last pyspark version

I did this way:

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy(F.col('version')).orderBy(F.col('count_granularity').desc())

window_granularity= Window.partitionBy(F.col('version'),F.col('color'))

mode = df.orderBy('version'.withColumn('count_granularity', F.sum(F.lit(1)).over(window_granularity)) .withColumn('rank',F.row_number().over(window_spec)) .filter(F.col('rank') == 1) .withColumnRenamed('color', 'mode').select('version','mode')

df=df.join(mode, on='version', how='left') .withColumn('mode_color', F.when(df.color.isNull(), mode.mode).otherwise(df.color)).drop('color', 'mode') .withColumnRenamed('mode_color', 'color')
```

Comment: can you please share a toy example of your dataframe to test our approaches? see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the join and do everything with window

here's an example

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

# given the input data
# +-------+------+
# |version|colour|
# +-------+------+
# |      1|   red|
# |      1|   red|
# |      1|  null|
# |      1|yellow|
# +-------+------+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('colour_cnt', func.count('*').over(wd.partitionBy('version', 'colour'))). \
    withColumn('max_cnt', func.max(func.struct('colour_cnt', 'colour')).over(wd.partitionBy('version'))). \
    withColumn('colour_filled', func.coalesce('colour', func.col('max_cnt.colour'))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------+------+----------+--------+-------------+
# |version|colour|colour_cnt|max_cnt |colour_filled|
# +-------+------+----------+--------+-------------+
# |1      |null  |1         |{2, red}|red          |
# |1      |red   |2         |{2, red}|red          |
# |1      |red   |2         |{2, red}|red          |
# |1      |yellow|1         |{2, red}|yellow       |
# +-------+------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: I use first in the place of max, but it works too. Thank u!!!!